# How can I handle a click of the button from the Frame that is in Grid (SplitView)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, splitview

I've make the similar project like [here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/07/14/A-lap-around-the-SplitView-Control.aspx). But I've got a problem. I can't handle click from button or listview from the frame that is in grid (SplitView.Content). If I delete the grid and make a SplitView.Content only as a Frame, I can easily handle all manipulation on Frame. So... How can I make the same thing with `<Grid> <Frame /> </Grid>`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know why you cant handle click event from button. The button should be in a Page. And the Frame can navigate to the page to show content. In the link you provide, the ideal is having a Frame in SplitView.Content, which in turn show content from FirstPage / SecondPage / ThirdPage. The event should be handled there.

Comment: just check a project here https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-SplitView-Sample  and deploy it (don't forget to make a button on a page)